# Flutter tab/stepper bottom?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-android

My designer gave me the following design for a questionnaire screen.
I didn't found anything out of the box from the flutter components.

Maybe I could create something of my own, but before that I would like to validate that this isn't something that exists:

[image: First page]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you look at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Stepper-class.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `smooth_page_indicator`  or `page_indicator` for the page indicate, and for the Next and Back buttons you can use any kind of flutter button components

Comment: Oh thank you very much! will check if these do the trick :)